# Is there any way to search classification of USPTO?

Tags: uspto, search, us-class

Is there any way to to search classification of patent in CPC or USPC by keyword?

E.g I want to know what class "computer mouse" is, but it seems the search page assume that I already knew the code for that class. It seems the only way is to read all classification, which is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an alphabetical index of USPC classes that you can use. For example, if you look up the word "mouse", you'll see that they are included in class 345.

http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/uspcindex/indextouspc.htm